# How to handle concurrent updates in C# dotnet webapi without EF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, webapi

I have a claim voucher function that needs to get the first available code from a list of codes and 'claim it' by changing its status. The expected behavior of this function is that if it is called concurrently, each call should receive a different voucher code.

However, when I make 2 concurrent calls to this function, I get a deadlock error (the system automatically terminates 1 process and goes on with the other).

I have read that having my isolation level at Serializable is not recommended and is very likely causing the deadlock error. However, when the isolation level is set to anything else, and concurrent calls are made, all calls return the same voucher code.

```
public async Task<ClaimVoucherResponse> ClaimVoucher(ClaimVoucherRequest req)
        {
            using var connection = new SqlConnection(MSSQLConnectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
            var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;

            try
            {
                // this function makes a query like "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE voucherId={voucherId} AND status=1"
                var voucherCode = await GetAvailableCode(voucherId, cmd);

                // this function makes a query like "UPDATE table SET status={status} WHERE voucherCodeId={voucherCodeId}"
                await UpdateVoucherCode(voucherCode.Id, new SetVoucherCodeRequest
                {
                    Status = 2,
                }, cmd);
                transaction.Commit();
                return new ClaimVoucherResponse
                {
                    VoucherCode = voucherCode.VoucherCode,
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  ----- Message: {0}", ex.Message);
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

**What I have tried:**

If I set the isolation level to Serialization, I get a deadlock error

If I set the isolation level to anything else, the function returns the same voucher code to every concurrent call

Comment: Have you tried obtaining an exclusive lock on the voucher code at the beginning of the transaction? That should solve the deadlock problem.

Comment: Your comment says: `// this function makes a query like "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE status=1"`. So the query is not dependent on `voucherId`? That's strange.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but it might solve your problem if you were to just get the voucher code and update the status in one SQL statement, e.g. `UPDATE t SET Status = 2 OUTPUT inserted.VoucherCode FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE status=1 ORDER BY VoucherCode) AS t;`

Comment: @GarethD it does answer the question, even if the OP doesn't think so. Read before update causes most blocking issues. That UPDATE removes the need for an existing transaction completely.

Comment: Are you trying to implement some kind of queue over a table? Using the same table for both data and queue requires complex locking and can still fail, either by skipping items or blocking too much. A better way is to actually emulate a real queue, where poping an item removes it from the queue. `DELETE TOP 1 ... OUTPUT deleted.* ORDER BY ...`  will retrieve the first item in an atomic operation and remove it from the queue

Comment: @MoB. I'm still fairly new to C#. Do you know how i can obtain an exclusive lock on the voucher code? Or does it have to be done in the SQL statement


@GarethD I had assumed that having the `BeginTransaction` meant that all queries made within it would be made as if it were a single SQL query

@PanagiotisKanavos Your suggestion means I have to delete rows from the table? I don't really understand the query

Comment: @Russell this isn't about C# at all. It's about SQL and databases. Locks are held for the duration of a connection or transactions. Keeping connections or trasactions open for long increases the chance of conflicts. That's why all docs and *food* tutorials create connections in a `using` block, never store it in a field. A read followed by UPDATE *is* longer by a single UPDATE with an OUTPUT clause and thus increases the chances of blocking and deadlocks.

Comment: `all queries made within it would be made as if it were a single SQL query` yes, but that doesn't mean they take the same locks. A SELECT takes Shared locks which allow other reads but block updates. UPDATE takes an Exclusive lock which prevents other operations. The locks are taken on all the rows the database touches. If the query needs to scan all rows because there's no useful index, then the entire table will be locked. Instead of telling SELECT to use an Exclusive lock with UPDLOCK, it's better to *avoid* the read whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but more of a demonstration that the simple update is  thread safe (anecdotally at least). The demo set up is as follows.

Create a voucher table and populate with a million unallocated vouchers, and a log table we'll use to check for duplicate allocations:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Voucher;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Voucher (VoucherID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, SessionID INT NULL);
GO
INSERT dbo.Voucher (SessionID)
SELECT TOP 1000000 NULL
FROM sys.all_objects AS a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS a2;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.VoucherLog;
CREATE TABLE dbo.VoucherLog(VoucherID INT NOT NULL, SessionID INT NOT NULL);
```

Then in as many sessions as you please (I chose 10) run the following code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Voucher AS v WHERE v.SessionID IS NULL)
BEGIN

    UPDATE  v
    SET     SessionID = @@SPID
    OUTPUT inserted.VoucherID, inserted.SessionID INTO dbo.VoucherLog (VoucherID, SessionID)
    FROM    (SELECT TOP (1) v.VoucherID, v.SessionID FROM dbo.Voucher AS v WHERE v.SessionID IS NULL ORDER BY v.VoucherID) AS v;

END
```

You can then check to see if the same voucher ID has been updated twice:

```
SELECT VoucherID
FROM dbo.VoucherLog --WITH (NOLOCK) -- Uncomment if you want to check while other threads are running
GROUP BY VoucherID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I was running on my localdb and it quickly slowed my machine down so I didn't run until all vouchers had been allocated, but with 10 sessions simultaneously updating for 5 minutes, there was not one duplicate.

If you need to do additional updates/inserts on other tables then do so after the voucher code has been returned and the lock on the voucher table released, at worse if you need to set voucher back to available you could set the status back to 1 and it would be picked up at the next available opportunity

Answer (score -1):

1. You should avoid SELECT * in production code, always select only the columns you need.
2. An UPDLOCK lock is required to stop the deadlocks. If the isolation is not serializable the query needs to be so GetAvailableCode() should be:

   SELECT TOP (1) VoucherCode
   FROM table WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
   WHERE [status] = 1
   ORDER BY VoucherCode;

This is not very good for concurrency. Sequences might be an alternative.

3. As mentioned, you can avoid the .Net transaction by doing everything in one SQL statement. Assuming VoucherCode is the PK:

   WITH Voucher
   AS
   (
   SELECT TOP (1) VoucherCode, [status]
   FROM [table] WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
   WHERE [status] = 1
   ORDER BY VoucherCode
   )
   UPDATE Voucher
   SET [status] = 2
   OUTPUT inserted.VoucherCode;

Comment: No, an UPDLOCK will actually make this a lot worse. Locking problems aren't solved by *more* locks kept for longer but having *less* locks held for less time. GarethD's comment actually removes the need for an explicit transaction and thus the need for a long-lived lock

Comment: Unfortunately GarethD's code will allow two sessions to read the same VoucherCode before only one of them is able to apply the XLOCK. Using UPDLOCK will only allow one session to read the row and block the other session until the commit. Having the transaction occur as quickly as possible with one Statement is, of course, a good thing.

Comment: There is no "read" in my code, so it is not possible for two sessions to read the same code. It is a simple update statement and the update lock that goes with it is sufficient to prevent a race condition. SQL server cannot update the same row concurrently, so even if two statements target the same row, one must "win" the race, so by the time the second session attempts to update it the row no longer satisfies the predicate of status = 1, so would not be the target for the second session anymore. What I have suggested is threadsafe without any additional explicit locking or transactions

Comment: @GarethD the function i gave above has been simplified. The actual function reads from 3 tables - Vouchers, VoucherCodes and Users - puts the data through some logic and updates 1 row from each table. What would you suggest in such a case?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could you explain why using UPDLOCK makes things a lot worse? This seems to be the most intuitive solution

Comment: @Russell presumably only one of those tables is susceptible to a race condition (i.e. I assume you're not running the risk of doing the same action to the same user twice?), so my approach likely wouldn't change. It'd help to see the actual scenario, but as Panagiotis has said, the solution to locking problems isn't to take more locks, it is to change the approach so that fewer locks are held for less time (without allowing a race condition obviously)